# Checking Multiple Keywords in a HashSet, and generating and outcome based on that

Tags: java, if-statement, hashset

I have a String which contains a long paragraph. This paragraph contains various keywords, like "happy", "sad", "disappointed", "satisfied" etc. After searching for this keywords in the paragraph I am trying to generate an outcome.

```
public static String fileReader() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String paragraph = "";
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file_Path"));
            JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) obj;
            paragraph = (String) jsonobject.get("paragraph");
            return paragraph;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return paragraph;
    }

// adding the words of the paragraph into a hashset.

public static String sentiment() {
String input20 = fileReader();
Set<String> items = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(input20.split(" ")));

//Array of Keywords
String arr[] = {"happy", "sad", "disappointed", "satisfied"};

if ((items.contains("happy")) || (items.contains("satisfied")) {
return "Positive";
} else if ((items.contains("sad")) || (items.contains("disappointed"))) {
return "Negative";
} else if ((items.contains("happy")) || (items.contains("satisfied")) && (items.contains("sad")) || (items.contains("disappointed"))) {
return "Mixed";
else {
return "Unknown";
}
}
```

Now, I want to write an if-else loop so that I can give output based on various conditions.
Conditions:
(1) If contains "Happy", 'Satisfied" or(any 1 on those), positive as output.
(2) if contains "Sad", "disappointed" or(any 1 on those), negative asoutput.
(3) If contains "Sad", "Happy", i.e(mixture of words), mixed as output.
(4) else unknown.

Can someone help me out with this logic? I always get the output as the first condition that I have kept.

Comment: _I always get the output as the first condition that I have kept._ This is the last sentence in your question and I don't understand what you mean. Does method `sentiment` always return _Positive_ ? Can you [edit] your question and post sample contents of the file you are reading?

Comment: Yes. The output always returns positive!

Example:

**Returned String from fileReader():** I am very happy about the application performance but I am disappointed how it shuts off sometimes.

HashSet **items** contains the words from the above sentence. Since the sentence contains "happy" and "disappointed", the loop should return "Mixed" instead it returns "positive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the array of keywords, so I ignore it in the below code.

You want the outcome to be *Positive* if the paragraph contains the words *happy* or *satisifed* **and not the words** ***sad*** **or** ***disappointed***. Hence you need to change the first `if` condition.

Similarly for the *Negative* outcome. You want paragraph to contain *sad* or *disappointed* but not contain *happy* or *satisfied*.

In short, each condition needs to consider all the keywords and not just some of them.

Consider the below code.

```java
String input20 = "I am very happy about the application performance but I am disappointed how it shuts off sometimes";
Set<String> items = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(input20.split(" ")));

//Array of Keywords (not used)
String arr[] = {"happy", "sad", "disappointed", "satisfied"};

String str;
if ((items.contains("happy") || items.contains("satisfied")) && !(items.contains("sad") || items.contains("disappointed"))) {
    str = "Positive";
} else if ((items.contains("sad") || items.contains("disappointed")) && !(items.contains("happy") || items.contains("satisfied"))) {
    str = "Negative";
} else if ((items.contains("happy") || items.contains("satisfied")) && (items.contains("sad") || items.contains("disappointed"))) {
    str = "Mixed";
}
else {
    str = "Unknown";
}
System.out.println("Outcome: " + str);
```